# Shopify Render some HTML only if product has certain tag

Tags: shopify, liquid

Shopify Render some HTML only if the product has a certain tag
THE  Problem is if the tag is 2 times it duplicates
if i hvae  'new' and  'new 1'

how to limit to show 1-time per page

```
  {% for tag in product.tags %}
    {% if tag contains 'new' %}
         <div class="new-tag new-tag--absolute"> NEW </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{% break %}` to exit a `for` loop.  Once you've discovered one 'new' tag, you can exit your loop.

```
   {% for tag in product.tags %}
     {% if tag contains 'new' %}
          <div class="new-tag new-tag--absolute"> NEW </div>
          {% break %}
     {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: thank you. this what i was looking for